# ggplot2 Grouping histogram bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems with grouping the bars of my histogram.

This is part of the dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Color = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "red"), class = "factor"),
                       Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), class = "factor"),
                       ID = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "D1", "D2"), class = "factor"), 
                       Value = c(194L, 1446L, 0L, 17L, 77L, 2565L, 223L, 61L)), 
                  .Names = c("Color", "Group", "ID", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I build the histogram as follow:

```
ggplot(data, aes(ID, Value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Color), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "Red"))
```

Now I would group the bars of the histogram by the variable Group, but I found it impossible using facet_wrap:

```
ggplot(data, aes(ID, Value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Color), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "Red")) + facet_wrap(. ~ Group)
```

> Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
>       At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting.

It would be just as fine having the groups spaced from each other.

How can I do that? Someone can help me?

Comment: Get rid off the `.` in `facet_wrap`, the correct code: `facet_wrap( ~ Group)`

Comment: I tried with and without . but it doesn't work in any case

Comment: On my machine, it works (as in, produces a faceted plot) when I leave out the `.`. Do you get an error, or is the plot produced not what you want?

Comment: You had `Values` in your `aes`, but in your dataframe there is only a column `Value`. I corrected that in the question already.

Comment: @Heroka R gives me the same error: Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) and doesn't plot anything. Maybe there is a problem with my R version (3.1.2)

Comment: Did you try the exact code from my answer below? As you can see, it produces the plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `.`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(ID, Value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Color), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "Red")) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Group)
```

this will give you the following plot:

[image]

When you want to improve the plot, include `scales = "free_x"` in the `facet_wrap` part. This get rid off the unnecessary values on the x-axis:

```
ggplot(data, aes(ID, Value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Color), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "Red")) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Group, scales = "free_x")
```

this will give you:

[image]

If you want the bars of equal width, it's better to use the `space` argument in `facet_grid`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(ID, Value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Color), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue", "Red")) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Group, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you and @Heroka I finally faceted the histogram. Now a new problem rises, can I have only the interested part of the x axis in each facet?

Comment: @Valentina What do you mean with interested parts? If I understand you correctly, the 2nd and 3rd option in my answer will give you that.

Comment: With facet_grid(. ~ Group, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") it worked! Sorry for the troubles. Thank you very much!!!